# Distance function in Point class is not returning the correct value despite the formula being coded properly

Tags: c++, function, class, formula

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Point{
    int x,y;
    
    public:
    Point(){
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }
    Point(int a, int b){
        a=1;
        b=1;
    }
    Point(const Point &a){
        x=a.x;
        y=a.y;
    }
    void setvalues(int a, int b){
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }
    int getvalueX(){
        return x;
    }
    int getvalueY(){
        return y;
    }
    double distance(const Point &a,const Point &b){
        int x1=a.x,x2=b.x,y1=a.y,y2=b.y;
        double d=sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2))+((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));
        return d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Point pointA;
    Point pointB;
    pointA.setvalues(9,7);
    pointB.setvalues(3,2);
    cout<<pointA.getvalueX()<<","<<pointA.getvalueY()<<endl<<pointB.getvalueX()<<","<<pointB.getvalueY()<<endl<<distance(&pointA,&pointB);
    return 0;
}
```

I used the formula in another program and it worked just fine. I'm new to c++ so I'm guessing that I just coded something incorrectly. ***ignore the rest it keeps telling me that I need to add more details to post this question. Annoying.***

Comment: This is why you [don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/9254539). You're calling [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) on two pointers, instead of your own function which is a member of the class and takes references instead of pointers.

Comment: `double d=sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2))+((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));` - please don't ever write that. Break it up into smaller components.

Comment: @Jesper seems like a style thing. That line is perfectly readable to me. Could use a little more horizontal whitespace for my taste but the Pythagorean Theorem is pretty recognizable.

Comment: @JohnFilleau -- Maybe it looks readable because the distance formula is well known.  If it was a more obscure formula, it may not look as readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `distance` a static member function. This way you can access the private elements and don't need an object to call the method on.

```
static double distance(const Point &a,const Point &b){
    int x1=a.x,x2=b.x,y1=a.y,y2=b.y;
    double d=sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2))+((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));
    return d;
}
```

You can make it a friend function with

```
friend double distance(const Point &a,const Point &b){
    int x1=a.x,x2=b.x,y1=a.y,y2=b.y;
    double d=sqrt(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2))+((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)));
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you declare `distance()` as a member function of `Point`, you must call it as a member function of a `Point`.

Your code

`cout << distance(pointA, pointB);`

*will not* work because it ignores the fact that `distance` must be called as a member function. To fix this, change the output statement to

`cout << pointA.distance(pointA, pointB) << endl;`

Note: As `@cigien` stated in the comments, a better way to implement the `distance` function would be to make it a non-member function

```
double distance(Point a, Point b){
    return something;
}
```

or make it a member function with only one parameter:

```
struct Point{
    double x, y;

    double distance_to(Point b){
        return something;
    }
}
```

Comment: It has to be a friend function or a static member function to access the private elements.

Comment: To be clear, I'm writing this code as a college assignment and we haven't reached the topic of friend functions so I'm going to have to use a static member function but I don't know how to do that to be honest. Can you maybe give me some sample code to work with please?